# React unwanted rerendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, state, rerender

```
const [filtersection, setFilterSection] = React.useState("categories");

const leftSideBar = () => {
      return (
        <div className="leftsidebarbody">
          <div onClick={() => setFilterSection("categories")}>Categories</div>
          <div onClick={() => setFilterSection("prices")}>Price</div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    const rightSideBar = () => {
      return (
        <div className="rightsidebarbody">
          {filtersection === "categories" && (
            <div className="block">
              {categories.map((category, index) => {
                return (
                  <div className="categories" key={index}>
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id={category._id}
                      onChange={handleCheck}
                      checked={selectedCategories.includes(category._id)}
                    />
                    <div>{category.name}</div>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          )}
          {filtersection === "prices" && (
            <div className="block">
              {prices.map((price, index) => {
                return (
                  <div className="categories" key={index}>
                    <input
                      name={price}
                      value={`${price._id}`}
                      type="radio"
                      onChange={handlePrice}
                      checked={selectedPrice.includes(price._id)}
                    />
                    {price.name}
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Both the leftsidebar and rightsidebar sections are placed inside same component Whenever I price any input button inside price the component rerenders and the filtersection value is set to categories.

And the component is rendered as a child inside Parent component which is itself rendered as a page.

Comment: `Please reply ASAP.` Nobody here works for you..

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox link?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your `handlePrice()` and `handleCheck()` functions.

Comment: const handleCheck = (event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();

      console.log(event);
      const { id, checked } = event.target;

      setSelectedCategories([...selectedCategories, id]);
      if (!checked) {
        setSelectedCategories(selectedCategories.filter((item) => item !== id));
      }
    };
    const handlePrice = (event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      const { value } = event.target;
      setFilterSection("prices");
      setSelectedPrice(value);
      console.log(filtersection, "price");
    };